# Preserving spaces for character type in SELECT

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to preserve the padded spaces in character(N) type in select?

That is

```
SELECT left(' 10  '::character(5), 3), right(' 10  '::character(5), 2)
```

should return

```
' 10', '  '
```

but it returns

```
' 10', '10'
```

Can I somehow tell the system to preserve all the spaces and don't do any trimming?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6

Thanks

Comment: `right(expression,number) should return number of last chars from expression - I would expect two spaces returned instead

Comment: what is your initial task here?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I just want to format the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

> right(str **text**, n int) Return last n characters in the string.
>   When n is negative, return all but first |n| characters.

which actually happens when you use variable length string:

```
t=# SELECT left(' 10  '::character(5), 3), right(' 10  '::character varying(5), 2);
-[ RECORD 1 ]
left  |  10
right |
```

it returns two spaces

As Abelisto says in his answer, [the documentation clearly states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) on **character** data type:

> Trailing spaces are removed when converting a character value to one
>   of the other string types.

so `right` and `left` will remove spaces by their definition. to avoid it you need to use varying text

**update**

when you explicitly cast char(5) to text, spaces are removed - to avoid it, you can use function that does not implicitly cast any string to text before processing and thus respecting your ending spaces, eg `concat`:

```
t=# with a(v) as (select ' 10  '::character(5))
, monkey_cast as (select concat(v,'') v from a)
select quote_ident(v),left(v,3), right(v,3) from monkey_cast;
 quote_ident | left | right
-------------+------+-------
 " 10  "     |  10  | 0
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation, but the `char(N)` was already type for the given column in the table and wanted to know if there isn't some other method, than to change to `varchar(N)`.

Comment: that's why I asked about the initial task :) updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

It is "feature" of the `character` type - it considers trailing spaces as insignificant:

```
select quote_ident(' 10  '::char(5)), quote_ident(' 10  '::varchar(5)); 
┌─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ quote_ident │ quote_ident │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ " 10"       │ " 10  "     │
└─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

So if your care about trailing spaces - use `varchar` or `text` type instead.

Comment: Probably, this is the right direction, but wanted to know other "non-intrusive" options.